# @override annotation

Tags: java, annotations

Can anyone tell me if this code:

```
public class OvTester {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return toString().hashCode();
    }
}
```

determines that the `toString` method in the `OvTester` class overrides the `toString` method in its superclass.

I'd like to know if this is true, and if so how it works?

If it's not true, then is this true:

*"the `hashCode()` method in `OvTester` must override the same name method in its superclass"*

?

If that's not correct then what is correct?

Comment: Your class doesn't seem to have a superclass, so this would fail.

Comment: of course it has a superclass - `java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Method overriding happens when you redefine a method with the same signature in a sublcass.

So here you are overriding `hashCode()`, not `toString()`

The `@Override` annotation is optional (but a very good thing) and indicates that this is expected to be overriding. If you misspell something or have a wrongly-typed parameter, the compiler will warn you.

So yes, the 2nd statement is true (and the superclass in this case is `java.lang.Object`)

Answer (score 2):

> ***I'd like to know if this is true, and if so how it works?***

No, it's not exactly true.

The `@Overrides` annotation says that "*this method overrides the method **with the same name**  in the super class*".

In this case the `hashCode` of `OvTester` overrides the `hashCode` in `Object`.

> ***if its not true, then is this true: the `hashCode()` method in `OvTester` must override the same name method in its superClass?***

Yes. That's exactly how it works.

---

When one method doesn't do anything else than to call another method (almost what you got in your example) it is usually referred to as a [*delegate method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Examples). Perhaps that's what you're confusing this with.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Override` annotation does not "determine" anything.  It is simply a flag that tells the compiler to raise an error if the annotated method is not overriding a superclass or interface method.  It's a tool for developers to help maintain their sanity, and nothing more.

In this specific case, it is simply noting that the `hashCode()` implementation in `OvTester` is overriding the `hashCode()` method defined in `Object`.  This has nothing at all to do with `toString()`, and calling the superclass's `toString()` method from your `hashCode()` method will not/is not the same thing as overriding `toString()`.

> is this true? the hashCode() method in OvTester must override the same
>   name method in its superClass?

That is indeed true, in the sense that the annotation will cause the compiler to raise an error if there is not an overridable `hashCode()` method in the superclass that matches the signature of the annotated method.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will only mean that the hashCode() method is being overridden. The compiler will check at compile time that hashCode() really is a method (with that signature) that is being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

That code overrides the `hashCode()` method form the base `Object` class.
The `toString()` method still has the original implementation.

To override the `toString()`, you do the following:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    //Your own toString() implememntation here
}
```

As long as the method in the child class has the same name and signature as the method in the parent class, **AND** the method in the parent class is **NOT** private it will be overidden(regardless of the presence of the annotation `@Override`)

Answer (score -1):

`@Override` is just compile time check if the implementer really overrides the method.

if you try overriding

```
@Override
public void equals(Object ob){

}
```

it will fail to compile