# Facing issue with Merging in Shuffle & Sort of Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am rookie in Hadoop hence need your help on a piece of code. My Mapper output is:   Gender Age

> Male   38
>   Female 23
>   Female 26 ... 100 rows like this

**OBJECTIVE:** I want to calculate Average age of Male and avg age of Female as well. The idea seems quite simple but I am getting the wrong output. Please have a look at my reducer code pls.

```
public static class AgeRed extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void Red(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException , InterruptedException {

            int sum=0, count=0;
            for(IntWritable i : values){
                count++;
                sum+=i.get();
            }
            int a =sum/count;
            IntWritable avg = new IntWritable(a);
            context.write(key, avg);
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer output :

> Female 23
>   Female 26
>   .
>   .
>   Male   38   ... All such rows but it is not merging like
>
> Female 23,26,28 ..
>   Male 38,34,42...

It is not combining the keys only sorting it and my reducer jobs are NOT set to zero please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

`Red(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)`

to

`reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)`

Because of the name you aren't actually overriding the reduce method, so it will be calling the default implementation in the `Reducer` class which is effectively just writes out each key/value which is what you seem to be seeing.

Comment: Thanks a ton man @Binary http://stackoverflow.com/users/256376/binary-nerd  , also thanks for not downvoting my Question usually with such silly questions my question rating goes in negative :D

Comment: No problem, i hope it helped. Just accept/upvote if this sorted you out.

Comment: Also, you can avoid this sort of a problem in the future by adding the `@Override` annotation to any method you are overloading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160479/override-annotation

Comment: yeah thats a good idea usually with Java the compiler does that , so have to be careful in hadoop and I have upvoted your answer but it won't display my vote as I have less badges but surely it will be recorded. :)